# Capture the "+" key using autoit

Tags: autoit

I am trying to capture the <kbd>+</kbd> key using AutoIt. I wrote this line of code:

```
HotKeySet("{+}", "plus")
```

But this code doesn't work. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Send Auto Keys List](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm)

The character of the send is the same as logging it. AutoIT is a very nice language and I don't think you should abandon it if your code doesn't work the first time.

```
HotKeySet("{NUMPADADD}", "reactionFunction")

While 1
    ;a loop
WEnd

Func reactionFunction()
    MsgBox(0, "You pressed +", "You pressed +")
    Exit
EndFunc
```

This code is tested and works on my computer.
Windows 7 64 Bit

Comment: Try using it on your keyboard not your number pad. It only work on my keyboard not my number pad.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin take a look at my update. + on the number pad takes into account "add" because it is dealing with number. SO {NUMPADADD} works on my keypad.

Note that was found on http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Everything keystroke that you need is on there for future reference.